# How UDF function works in pyspark with dates as arguments?

Tags: date, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I started in the pyspark world some time ago and I'm racking my brain with an algorithm, initially I want to create a function that calculates the difference of months between two dates, I know there is a function for that (months_between), but it works a little bit different from what I want, I want to extract the months from two dates and subtract without taking into account the days, only the month and the year, the point is, I can do this by manipulating base, creating new columns with the months and subtracting , but I want to do this as a UDF function, like below:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

base_study = spark.createDataFrame([("1", "2009-01-31", "2007-01-31"),("2","2009-01-31","2011-01-31")], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
base_study = base_study.withColumn("A",f.to_date(base_study["A"], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
base_study = base_study.withColumn("B",f.to_date(base_study["B"], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))


def intckSasFunc(RecentDate, PreviousDate):
    RecentDate = f.month("RecentDate")
    PreviousDate = f.month("PreviousDate")
    months_diff = (RecentDate.year - PreviousDate.year) * 12 + (RecentDate.month - PreviousDate.month)
    return months_diff
  
intckSasFuncUDF = f.udf(intckSasFunc, IntegerType())

base_study.withColumn('Result', intckSasFuncUDF(f.col('B'), f.col('A') ))
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Another question: When I pass parameters in a UDF function, they sent one by one or it pass entire column? And this column is a series?

Thank you!

Comment: no need to define a udf - you're calling native spark functions, not python functions. just use intckSasFunc directly

Comment: @mck unfortunately it didn't work that way, maybe it's because I'm passing the parameters using a col() sql function, I don't know, but I found a solution that I've put below, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and upgraded it to handle missings too.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

base_study = spark.createDataFrame([("1", None, "2015-01-01"),("2","2015-01-31","2015-01-31")], ['ID', 'A', 'B'])
base_study = base_study.withColumn("A",f.to_date(base_study["A"], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
base_study = base_study.withColumn("B",f.to_date(base_study["B"], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))


def intckSasFunc(RecentDate, PreviousDate):

  if (PreviousDate and RecentDate) is not None:
    months_diff = (RecentDate.year - PreviousDate.year) * 12 + (RecentDate.month - PreviousDate.month)
    return months_diff
  else:
    return None 

intckSasFuncUDF = f.udf(lambda x,y:intckSasFunc(x,y) , IntegerType())

display(base_study.withColumn('Result', intckSasFuncUDF(f.col('B'), f.col('A'))))
```

for those who have doubts, as I had, the function treats one record at a time, as if it were a normal python function, I couldn't use pyspark.sql functions inside this UDF, it gives an error, it seems, these functions are used only in pypsark columns, and inside the UDF the transformation is row by row.